# Docker with websphere and switching websphere version keeping profile

Tags: docker, websphere

I work at this moment on docker. I wish I could change Websphere version just changing my Websphere image. But problem, I don't want to lose my Websphere profile.

Websphere images are listed at this link : https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-traditional/

I have already tested method at this link : https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2016/04/27/upgrading-traditional-docker-containers-latest-fixpack/

But this doesn't work. I tested install of a profile into websphere 9.0.0.2 image. Profile files are stored on my local disk and are mounted at running of image with -v flag and replace original files from image.

And when I take another version like websphere 9.0.0.3 image using my profile created previously in websphere 9.0.0.2, I have incompatibilities like "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource"

Do you have any solution to do this ? Or it is not possible and why ?

Comment: Did you install the JDBC driver in the 9.0.0.3 image?

Comment: No I forgot this, it is ok, it was this problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where are the files for the profile being stored?  Do you have them going to a persistent location or just inside the package?  If they are inside the package that is your problem as replacing the package or even deploying the same on a new docker node will re-create the layer and you will loose your profile information.

If that is the case, move your profile files to a more persistent location such as a file mount of some sort depending on your environment.

Comment: Profile files are stored on my local disk and are mounted at running of image with -v flag and replace original files from image

Comment: Did you mount this in the new image?  Did you enter the container interactively to validate you can read the file?  Could be a permission issue or maybe IBM changed the config file layout which could be causing such java errors.